# Loop with Custom Post Type and Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop

Regards, i've a problem.

What i want: Show a toggle with loop from Custom Post Type

I create post type: **Episodio**

And a Taxonomy: **Temporada**

I create this loop:

```
   <?php
        $post_type = 'episodio'; // <-- Post Type
        $tax = 'temporada'; // <-- Taxonomía
        $termino = get_terms($tax);
        if ($termino) {
            foreach ($termino as $temporada) {
            $args=array(
              'post_type' => $post_type,
              "$tax" => $temporada->slug,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
              'cat' => 'serie',
              'meta_key'=> 'numeroepisodio',
              'order_by'=> 'meta_value',
              'order' => 'ASC'
            );
        $query_episodios = null;
        $query_episodios = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $query_episodios->have_posts() ) {
          echo '<h3 class="titulo-temp" id="titulo-temp-'.$temporada->slug.'" onclick="tog(\''.$temporada->slug.'\')" ><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'.$temporada->name.'</h3><hr> <ul id="items-temp-'.$temporada->slug.'" class="items-temp">';
          while ($query_episodios->have_posts()) : $query_episodios->the_post(); 
          $numeroepisodio = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'numeroepisodio',true); ?>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><li><strong><?php  echo 'Episodio '.$numeroepisodio; ?>:</strong> <?php the_title(); ?> <img src="//cdn.enlatino.net/img/play.png" class="img-play"></li></a>
        <?php endwhile; } wp_reset_query(); } }?>
```

**The result its correct, and work!** but, this loop its same for all posts.

The loop come in a page template, if i create another page with this page template, the result its same.

I want to use one page template to all posts.

I don't know if i do this correctly, but the result what i want is something like this:

Serie 1:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ43M.png

Serie 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eJds.png

Problem and my loop in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80TtS.png

Same template to 2 series, only change the loop. But i don't know how to do this.

Sorry for my english, i'm from Argentina.

Thanks.

Comment: In your `$args` array you shoule change `"$tax"` to `'tax_query'` and add a proper **tax_query** - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: @DavidGard that is valid usage and should work. However, to make this work, you will need to set `query_var` to true when registering your taxonomy.

Comment: `caller_get_posts` is depreciated many years ago. Please turn debug on as you should have gotten a depreciation message if you had debug turned on. You should use `ignore_sticky_posts`. Also, what is `cat` and what is `serie`. The `cat` parameter only except a category ID, and only works with the build in taxonomy `category`

Comment: i've really problem with the organization of the post type and taxonomies. `tax_query` doesn't work. i've quit `caller_get_posts` thanks. i forget to delete these line (cat=...)

Comment: I reorganize all. Create 1 taxonomy: `series`, and 2 post type: `episodio`, `temporada` and create a relationship with all this. But, now, i must create a correctly loop, to show the post type episodio and temporada in page template, filter by `taxonomy slug`; its ok my idea?

Comment: Please update your code with this new info **and** code

Comment: i don't know how do the loop. i only create the taxonomy and post types. Im googling and testing. When finish i update. Thanks.

Comment: @PieterGoosen - I should have been more specific - The OP should change to `tax_query` because the `{tax}` parameter is deprecated, and had been for some time (at least according to the Codex).

Comment: @PieterGoosen - I realise that, but it's still deprecated :) *"{tax} (string) - use taxonomy slug. **Deprecated as of Version 3.1** in favor of 'tax_query'."* It's only a comment to help improve the code, and is not intended to be an answer.

Comment: The general problem is the same content in all pages. If i "add" a category to custom post types, this maybe work?. I've no idea how to prevent the duplicate content in page templates. Sorry but this is new to me :|

Comment: Are you talking about taxonomy.php or page.php

Comment: In page.php i've the loop. I create a sample page, and the posts are showing ok, but when i create another sample page, this return the same posts from the first sample page.

Comment: That is expected yes, and also correct. I really don't know how your structures look like, but you should rather create a shortcode for that and change your terms accordingly